# local variable 'statement' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django

I am currently creating a while loop in python and I got this problem:

```
local variable 'statement' referenced before assignment
```

this is my code:

```
    while (statement == True):
        self.headNode = settings.EMPTY_UUID
        try:
            lastNode = Task.objects.get(next = self.headNode)
            self.headNode = lastNode.id
            statement = True
        except:
            statement = False
```

I am worried if I initialize statement = True before while statement because it might become an infinite loop

For instance, this is data of Task.objects:

```
id    name     next
001   task1    002
002   task2    003
003   task3    000
```

I would like to get the Id of the root task which should be `001`

Comment: if you can get an infinite loop on that then you should probably fix **that** issue with your DB linked list thing

Comment: _"I am worried if I initialize statement = True before while statement because it might become an infinite loop"_ - Why do you think that? Assuming your conditions for breaking control out of your loop are correct, you will not get an infinite loop. It looks like the real problem lies with the rest of your code. _**Start there**_

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with declaring `statement` to `True` before you loop. As a matter of fact, you could do `while True:` and then `break` out of the loop when a condition is met within the loop. You just need to think of what happens inside the loop and make sure it will get out of it **:)**

Comment: The error lies above your while loop. Make sure statement is defined regardless the path the code takes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments already point you to the answer, but here's a (more Pythonic) way to code this:

```
while True:
    self.headNode = settings.EMPTY_UUID
    try:
        lastNode = Task.objects.get(next=self.headNode)
        self.headNode = lastNode.id
        break
    except Task.DoesNotExist:
        break
```

Even if you'd need the value of `statement` after the while loop, you don't need the variable: `statement` is obviously `False` at that point.

Note that I've also changed the `except` statement. It's my assumption you want to catch the error that's raised when the relevant `Task` object does not exist, but it's generally bad to have a bare, catch-all, except.

Comment: I'm doing some linked lists here and my purpose is to get this headNode.

Comment: but it only gives me the first lastNode.id where the next is settings.EMPTY_UUID

Comment: @JamesReid I don't understand your last comment, but I guess that's actually another question anyway.